# How to plot a time distribution histogram with days and time in timedelta format - python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataframe showing unique ID's and the time duration for when they were active (i.e ID 1821 shows to be active for 170 days, 12hours, 34 mins and 12 seconds):

```
     ID      Duration

0  1821      170 days 12:34:12
1  1245       30 days 11:11:23
2  1345      110 days 15:12:01 
3  8782       22 days 22:01:11 
4  8123       21 days 01:13:42
5  9292        0 days 12:12:14
6  1921       11 days 22:11:41
7  1920       12 days 02:12:58
8  9182      160 days 21:11:04
```

Is there a way I can create a histogram using this data to show the time distribution across all the ID's (the original data contains 1 million rows)? Because the duration is not in a date format, I wasn't sure if there was a way to still create a histogram either using days or hours or minutes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.cut` to bin values of column `Duration` into discrete intervals of days, then use `Series.value_counts` + `Series.sort_index` on this categorical series to get the frequency distribution in each interval, then use `Series.plot` with optional argument `kind='bar'`:

```
bins = range(0, df['Duration'].max().days + 10, 10)
data = pd.cut(df['Duration'].dt.days, bins, include_lowest=True)
data.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')

plt.xlabel('Days Active')
plt.ylabel('Number of Users Active')
plt.title('Distribution of Active users')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @shuham: do you know how to plot the continuous distribution for durations (e.g., in case there are lots of IDs)? thank you!

Comment: @mOna Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, it's just resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

I converted all of the days and hours together to form a number, but I converted them all to seconds to visualize their frequency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import io

data = '''
 ID Duration
0  1821 "170 days 12:34:12"
1  1245 "30 days 11:11:23"
2  1345 "110 days 15:12:01" 
3  8782 "22 days 22:01:11" 
4  8123 "21 days 01:13:42"
5  9292 "0 days 12:12:14"
6  1921 "11 days 22:11:41"
7  1920  "2 days 02:12:58"
8  9182 "160 days 21:11:04"
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df1 = pd.concat([df['ID'], df['Duration'].str.split(' days ', expand=True)], axis=1)
df1.rename(columns={0:'days',1:'time'}, inplace=True)
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df1['days'] = df1['days'].astype(int)
df1['total_seconds'] = (df1['days'] * 24 * 60 * 60) + (df1['time'].dt.hour * 60 * 60) + (df1['time'].dt.minute * 60) + df1['time'].dt.second
df1[['total_seconds']].plot.hist(bins=12)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I ran this code with the rest of my data and I get the error message: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas -> Would you happen to know why this is the case?

Comment: I've taken the sample data as a string and included the corresponding process. I think a line from `df1['time']` will do the job.